# smtp code executes even though I stop the process

Tags: c#, email, debugging

I'm using the following code to open a text file and send emails to the people listed and changing the subject to include their ids.  The issue i'm having is that the first time through testing I stopped the debugger on the subject line.  The next thing I know I'm getting the test email.  How could the code continue to execute even when I stopped the debugger?

Here is my code:

```
protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string sFilePath = @"C:\email\" + ddlYear.SelectedItem.Value + "-" + ddlMonth.SelectedItem.Value + "_Num.txt";
        using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(sFilePath))
        {
            parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.FixedWidth;
            parser.SetFieldWidths(4, -1);
            int iRowCnt = 1;

            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] sCurrRow = parser.ReadFields();

                try
                {
                    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("test@test.com", sCurrRow[1].ToString());
                    message.Subject = txtSubject.Text + " - ID #" + sCurrRow[0].ToString() ;
                    message.IsBodyHtml = Convert.ToBoolean(ddlFormat.SelectedValue);
                    message.Body = txtMsg.Text;
                    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient mailClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
                    mailClient.Host = "testSMTP.test.com";
                    mailClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("TestSMTP", "TESTING");  //Username and password changes
                    mailClient.Send(message);

                    this.InsEmailDB(iRowCnt, iRowCnt, sCurrRow[1].ToString());
                    iRowCnt++;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }                    
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you know when you stop the debugger it hasn't already looped through X people or know that the email wasn't from an earlier test?  I'd also HIGHLY recommend using  the `using` keyword for disposing of the SmtpClient (implements IDisposable).

Comment: Do you mean to put using around the creation of mailClient?  Is there a dispose property for mailClient?  Thank you for your reply.

Comment: [Msdn - SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stopping the debugger doesn't terminate the program, it just stops "watching" it-- the program will still run to completion.

Comment: you should move the execution line (debugger) to the end of the function if you are concerned.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging as it's name suggests, is to error free the application. It only show you how it is executing. Stopping debug doesn't mean stopping application. And I think receiving test mail isn't big issue.

Comment: it could be a big deal if it was getting sent out to accounts that aren't his.

Comment: @pennstatephil Testing means testing. He shouldn't include any account that may concern him.

Comment: Thank you for all the responses.  I now understand that debugging doesn't stop the process from completing and that is just allowing me to watch the process.  I'm using a list of my own email accounts as not to have happen to the actual emails I do need to send out.